# Converting an evolutionary algorithm to genetic

Tags: java, algorithm, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

From what I can tell one of the biggest differences between evolutionary and genetic algorithms is that evolutionary employs a mutate function to generate a new population while a genetic used a crossover function.

I found an [evolutionary algorithm](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Evolutionary_algorithm#Java) that trys to generate a target string through mutations like this:

```
  private static double newMutateRate(){
    return (((double)perfectFitness - fitness(parent)) / perfectFitness * (1 - minMutateRate));
  }

  private static String mutate(String parent, double rate){
    String retVal = "";
    for(int i = 0;i < parent.length(); i++){
      retVal += (rand.nextDouble() <= rate) ?
        possibilities[rand.nextInt(possibilities.length)]:
        parent.charAt(i);
    }
    return retVal;
  }
```

I wrote this crossover function to replace the mutation function:

```
private static String crossOver(String parent)
{
    String newChild = "";
    for(int i = 0;  i < parent.length(); i++)
    {
        if(parent.charAt(i) != target.charAt(i))
            newChild += possibilities[rand.nextInt(possibilities.length)];
        else
            newChild += parent.charAt(i);
    }
    return newChild;
}
```

Which works great. **But I'm wondering if its a valid crossover function**. I feel like, from my experience with genetic algorithms, that the crossover function should be generating more random populations than what I have written in other words knowing exactly which bit not to change seems almost like cheating.

Comment: The assumption in your first paragraph ("that evolutionary employs a mutate function to generate a new population while a genetic used a crossover function") is wrong. The difference is that genetic algorithm are a subtype of evolutionary algorithms that explicitly use "genes" to model an individual's characteristics. Read [this Wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_algorithm#Evolutionary_algorithm_techniques)  for a comparison of EAs.

Comment: @Junuxx this problem is not the most practical problem to be solved by GA but only learning purpose one as u already know the optimal target string which used for calculation of fitness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your crossover function does not fit the conventional meaning of the term. Crossover should take genes from **two** parents. What you have now is more like a mutation function.

**Uniform crossover** is a common crossover implementation of two genomes where the child gets approximately 50% of the genes of each parent. Here I assume the genome length is fixed.

```
private String crossover(String parent1, String parent2){

    String child = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < parent1.length(); i++){
        if (rand.nextFloat() >= 0.5){
            child += parent1[i];
        }
        else {
            child += parent2[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some psuedo code as to a valid crossover. In the past we've used the roulette wheel approach to determine which genes are more favorable but am not a 100% on how to implement this.

Comment: @Nick: See edit above. Don't confuse crossover with selection; crossover just generates new genomes and should concern itself with which genes are more favorable. It's by eliminating the weakest individuals that you get natural selection, and thus improvement over time.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not appropriate to use the target to construct crossover function but you should use two best strings in the current population for crossover.

Here is pseudo code for one such crossover:-

```
Crossover(String parent1,String parent2) {

 for(i=0;i<parent1.length;i++) {

       if(parent1[i]==target[i]) {
              child[i] = parent1[i]
       }
       else if(parent2[i]==target[i]) {
            child[i] = parent2[i]
       }
 } 

 insert remaining elements into child randomly

}
```

The above method is called a greedy crossover

Comment: "Two best strings" sounds like a type of [elitism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm#Elitism). This is often a good method, but not essential to the principle of crossover.

Comment: @Junuxx the above method would always produce a better string from any two parent , they need not be the best. It is converge faster in many cases if u use best strings.

Comment: Absolutely agree with the second part (I said the same thing in my previous comment), but with the first part only when looking at the target. Which is kind of cheating, @Nick, as it is supposed to be unknown in real applications of EA.

Comment: @Junuxx But wouldnt it be impossible to evaluate the fitness function without knowing the target string. This not the ideal problem to apply genetic algo.

Comment: No that wouldn't be impossible. Consider for example the goal of [learning how to control a racing car](http://torcs.sourceforge.net/). The fitness can be measured not by comparing the genome to the ideal genome (we have no idea what it looks like) but by measuring the actual performance: How far the did  the car drive before it crashed, or how much time did it take to complete a lap?

Comment: @Junuxx Yes that would be true in cases where we can compare two chromosomes and tell that which one is better in any way but in the above example if we do not know the target string we cannot get any clue about which one is better.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Junuxx, I just like to add one thing. It happens that genetic algorithms tend to use crossover operators more than other evolutionary algorithms, but it's not the reproduction operator that makes an algorithm genetic! I found that the Lawnmower example explains it very well (don't worry about the implementation code, just read the explanation):

[Lawnmower Problem Solver](http://handcraftsman.wordpress.com/2012/04/29/lawnmower-problem-solver/)